# Will `var allByDefault: Int ?` cause error?

Tags: kotlin

In the section: [Properties and Fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters) of the reference of kotlin, the following examples is written:

> var allByDefault: Int? // error: explicit initializer required, default getter and setter implied

However, I test the code and there is no error in compiling and running.
Here is my code"

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){
    var allByDefault:Int?
}
```

So why does the documentation write:

> error: explicit initializer required, default getter and setter implied

I have searched google for help but haven't found any result which can help me.

---

@toniedzwiedz 's answer has solved the issue. It's my fault. I mistook property and variable.

Comment: `allByDefault` in your code is a local variable, not a property.

Comment: @milleniumbug thank you for you reply. I have known why it confused me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){
    var allByDefault:Int?
}
```

What you have here is a `var` local to the `main` method, not a property.

```
class MyClass {

    //this is a property of MyClass that requires some means of initialization
    var allByDefault: Int? // Error: Property must be initialized or be abstract

    fun foo() {
       var local: Int? // this is a local variable defined in the scope of foo, which is fine
       // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: To add to this: it will still have to be initialized before its first use, but the compiler lets you declare it without an initial value because it can check that all of its usages occur after the initialization - unlike properties, which could be accessed from various places at various times. This lets you, for example, initialize it in different ways in an `if-else` or a `try-catch`.